How to securely manage access to sensitive secrets in AWS with strict user permissions?
I’m currently working on a project where we need to securely manage sensitive secrets, like API keys and seed phrases. Our team is small, and we don’t want these secrets to be accessible to anyone except the specific team member responsible. We’re considering tools like AWS Secrets Manager, Azure Key Vault, and others, but I’m curious to hear what best practices you follow in similar situations.
How do you manage:
Restricting access to specific roles (e.g., only one person can view/change the secret)?
Ensuring even admins don’t have access unless absolutely necessary?
Keeping everything audit-ready?
At Sajoki, we handle a lot of sensitive data for our recruitment tools and follow strict security measures for managing such secrets. But I’d love to hear how other companies or teams approach this!
Any recommendations or tips would be awesome!
We’ve been experimenting with AWS Secrets Manager and IAM policies to tightly control access. The idea was to allow only the designated person (in our case, a payment manager) to access specific secrets. While it works to some extent, we ran into challenges ensuring that even administrators couldn’t override or access the secret without explicit permissions.
At Sajoki, we’ve managed similar scenarios by combining role-based access controls with strict auditing, but I was hoping to find alternative methods or lesser-known tools that might work even better in small-team setups.
Any insights or suggestions would be amazing!

If you are looking for 'opinions', you might get a better response at: https://www.reddit.com/r/aws
